# QT Creator not read project

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I new in QT and here my errors. First. I download latest version of QT and when I`m starting a project, the program starts reading the project, and loops. Next, I installed an older version of QT and now I have this error when creating a project under Windows.

```
Project ERROR: You need to set the ANDROID_NDK_ROOT environment variable to point to your Android NDK.
Could not read qmake configuration file E:/QT/5.14.2/android/mkspecs/android-clang/qmake.conf.
Checking for updated license succeeded (2 licenses fetched)
E:/QT/5.14.2/mingw73_64/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf(76): Variable QMAKE_CXX.COMPILER_MACROS is not defined.
Project ERROR: failed to parse default search paths from compiler output
```

I didn't find a solution anywhere on the internet. Can someone help?

Comment: Please provide more details. Are you trying to create an Android project, first of all? If yes, re-do setup steps for having Android support. If not, do not try to create an Android build, maybe.

Comment: No, I try to make basic QT console project. I click on create project, select "QT Console Application", then build system - qmake, kit I select MinGW. Could this be a problem with the kit?

Comment: And I have this error immediately when creating a project

Comment: Maybe cleaning up (take backup!) local project config files from the project directory, especially `projectname.pro.*` (but not `projectname.pro`) will help... Except wait, you are creating a new project, so this isn't the issue then.

Comment: Also, checking the kits, and perhaps deleting (and re-creating if you need them) any manually kit configs should help.